# How does MPlayer recognize an MJPEG stream?

Tags: http, multimedia, encoder, decoder, mplayer

Since MJPEG over http consists basically on the transmission of a series of JPEG  images seperated by a defined seperator, how does MPlayer recognize that it is an MJPEG stream?

Thank you

Comment: How does any application recognise any video stream as a video stream? Mime types/content headers/tries to decode it and sees if it works.

Comment: Yes but since there is no formal specification for MJPEG,  there is no indications on how an MJPEG header should be...

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_JPEG#M-JPEG_over_HTTP seems to indicate that there's a special content type for it: `multipart/x-mixed-replace;boundary=<boundary-name>` Also https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2435 may be the spec for it (I'm not 100% sure about this though).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at:

[MplayerMjpegStreamViewing < Motion < Foswiki](http://www.lavrsen.dk/foswiki/bin/view/Motion/MplayerMjpegStreamViewing)

e.g.

```
mplayer -fps 4 -demuxer lavf http://rpi-6:8080/?action=stream
```

does the job for me. Suitable for a streaming server running on a Raspberry like this:

```
/usr/local/bin/mjpg_streamer -o output_http.so -w ./www -i input_raspicam.so -x 1920 -y 1440 -fps 3 -hf -vf
```